# Should I wait for material-ui v1 or can I use the pre-release now?

Tags: material-ui

Building a React.js dashboard (data tables + graphs) and styling this using [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui). If I use the pre-release version right now, will I have make more changes when the v1 of material-ui is released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend migrating as soon as you can.  It is not trivial, but you pay that price once to use the new features (like the new approach to style, CSS API, built in grid system/breakpoints, etc).  Any changes made to v1 should be easier to deal with as releases roll out.  Generally, the [release notes](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/releases) identify all of the changes, highlighting the breaking changes (if any were merged).

Check the [documentation](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/) and make sure all of the components you're using have been implemented.  If you find that v1 hasn't implemented a component you depend on, you have a few options:

1. Implement it and submit a PR :)
2. Implement a temporary version and wait for the official implementation
3. Run both versions of material-ui side by side using [yarn aliases](https://twitter.com/sebmck/status/873958247304232961) or by adding your own fork of material-ui as a git dependency/private package