# Am I able to use material-ui@next and the old version simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I have a project written with help of material-ui@next aka v1. However, I don't want to use the newest autocomplete (due to it's complexity) and I would rather choose the autocomplete from the older version of material-ui.

But the case is when I install v1 it removes the older version and vice versa when I install older version it removes v1 from dependencies.

Or even better - am I able to just shell the autocomplete from older version and inject it somehow to the v1?

Thanks!

Comment: You can, with yarn aliases. See the third option of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493755/should-i-wait-for-material-ui-v1-or-can-i-use-the-pre-release-now/45506472#45506472).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but rather than repeat the instructions here, let me link to the migration guide which describes how to achieve this: https://material-ui-next.com/guides/migration-v0.x#where-should-i-start-in-a-migration-